# Texmaker. Color in the editor. Math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, color, texmaker, editors

I am starting to use Texmaker with the default configuration.

When I use the math mode `($...$)` all of it is coloured in green in the editor, making long formulas difficult to follow.

I would like LaTeX commands such as `\frac` to be in a different color. It happens when I don't use the dollar signs, but of course I get an error then.

Comment: Options->Configure TeXmaker-->Editor->Colors->Math-->change `#008000` to `yourchoice color`, I have no idea on specific color change to `\frac`

Comment: As it stands, I suspect this is a feature request for Texmaker, which we can't answer and so is 'off topic' by convention.